# Error accesing modules Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I am using Joomla 2.5.14.

When I try to access to a module it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTable() on a non-object in H:\xxx\xxx\xxxx-001\www\httpdocs\libraries\joomla\application\component\controllerform.php on line 386
```

And when I try to create a new module it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in H:\xxx\xxx\xxxx-001\www\httpdocs\administrator\components\com_modules\views\module\view.html.php on line 56
```

PHP version is 5.2.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

I edit to add a print screen of the error:
[image]

Comment: What is the exact version of PHP you are using, 5.2....? Have you edited any core Joomla files? Has this happened only recently? If so, have you tried reverting any changines you have made in the mean time? Please update your site to Joomla 2.5.17

Comment: Have you modified the core? Have you installed an extension lately? Have you modified the database manually?

Comment: Php version: 5.2.12.
I dont touch anything.

Comment: Did it ever work properly?

Comment: Yes. I am going to try to mount it at localhost and to update to Joomla 2.5.17

Comment: It is also happening when I try to disable a module...

Comment: I have updated the Joomla version and it is running perfectly.
Thank you for your help